# Realm + kotlin android RealmMigrationNeededException: Field count is more than expected

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

Realm 2.1.1 + kotlin 1.1.3　の環境です。

maigrationの過程で必ず「RealmMigrationNeededException: Field count is more than expected」の例外が発生します。

migration前

```
public open class TestObject():RealmObject(){
@PrimaryKey
open var name:String = ""
open var age:Int = 0
}
```

migration後

```
public open class TestObject():RealmObject(){
@PrimaryKey
open var name:String = ""
open var age:Int = 0
open var hogehoge:String = ""//追加
}
```

migrationObject

```
class MyMigration:RealmMigration{

override fun migrate(realm: DynamicRealm?, oldVersion: Long, newVersion: Long) {
    Log.i("","oldVersion $oldVersion newVersion $newVersion")
    var oldVersion = oldVersion

    val schema = realm!!.schema

    if(oldVersion == 0L){
        var a = schema.get("TestObject")
        a.addField("hogehoge", String::class.java, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
        oldVersion++
    }
}
}
```

appllicationのmaigration部分

```
Realm.init(this)
    val builder = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
    builder.schemaVersion(1L).migration(MyMigration())
    val config = builder.build()
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
```

error発生箇所
MainActivity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Fabric.with(this,  Crashlytics(),  CrashlyticsNdk());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start)

    Log.i("mainActivity","startMainActivity")
    val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()//エラー発生
```

エラー内容

```
Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Field count is more than expected - expected 2 but was 3
at io.realm.TestObjectRealmProxy.validateTable(TestObjectRealmProxy.java:182)
at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.validateTable(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:186)
at io.realm.Realm.initializeRealm(Realm.java:344)
at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:301)
at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:280)
at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:143)
at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:211)
at jp.co.futaba_d.bluebear.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:103)
```

オブジェクトの種類を問わず必ず発生します。
どなたか、ご教授願えれば幸いです。

Comment: マイグレーションの処理が呼ばれてないように思います。マイグレーションのメソッドが呼ばれていることは確認できてますか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。このコードでは表示していませんが、マイグレーション処理は確かに呼ばれています。ログでも確認できました。また schema.get().fieldNamesをつかって「hogehoge」がschemaに追加されていることも確認済みです。

Comment: ただ、呼ばれるタイミングは「Realm.getDefaultInstance()」のタイミングです。このコードには書かれていませんが「Realm.migrateRealm()」も試して見ましたが、結果は同じでした。

Comment: マイグレーションが行われるのはRealmインスタンスを生成するときなので`Realm.getDefaultInstance()`のタイミングで正しいです。`Realm.migrate‌​Realm()`も基本的にはインスタンスを生成しているだけなので一緒です。Realmのバージョンがかなり古いので最新バージョン（3.5.0）でも再現するかやってみてください。またもし手元で問題が再現しているなら再現するプロジェクトとRealmファイルを`help@realm.io`まで送ってください。調べます。

Comment: 3.5.0で試したところ、同じエラーでだめでした。プロジェクトを送るのは・・・会社で作っているものなので公開はできないと思います。何か他に良い方法はないでしょうか？？

Comment: おそらくマイグレーションの処理が間違ってると思うのですがこれ以上は情報が足りないので難しいですね。質問に載せてるコードは実際のコードじゃないと思いますが、そんな感じで同じ問題が再現できればなんでもいいので、再現するサンプルを送ってもらえますか？

Comment: さきほど、同じ現象が確認できるプロジェクトとrealmファイルをお送りいたしました。ご確認ください。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: Realm Javaチームの山崎です。プロジェクト送付ありがとうございます。1点気になったのは、定義されたモデルには `@Required` アノテーションがついていないので、マイグレーションクラスでフィールドを追加する際 `FieldAttribute.REQUIRED` は不要という点です。 Kotlinでモデル定義した際、型が non-nullable ならば自動的に `@Required` 扱いにするというのは https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4701 で検討中です。いただいたプロジェクトはこれから確認します。

Comment: もう一点。  ` Field count is more than expected - expected 2 but was 3` となっていますが、プロジェクトが正しくビルドされていればこの部分は少なくとも `expected 3` となるはずです。これはコピペのミスではなく、実際に `expected 2` となっていたのでしょうか？もしそうだとすれば、一旦プロジェクトをclean してみたらなにか変わるでしょうか。

Comment: いただいたプロジェクトを試してみたところ、 `io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Field 'hogehoge' is required. Either set @Required to field 'hogehoge' or migrate using RealmObjectSchema.setNullable().` というエラーでクラッシュしていました。これは上に書いた `FieldAttribute.REQUIRED` の問題なので、これを削除するか、モデルクラスに `@Required` をつけて試してみてください。

Comment: あ、修正後にプロジェクトをcleanするのを忘れずに。

Comment: お世話になっております。治りました！原因はcleanでした。修正後にcleanをすると問題なくうごきました。初歩的なことなのに・・・盲点でした。ご指摘、ご指導誠にありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

定義されたモデルには `@Required` アノテーションがついていないので、マイグレーションクラスでフィールドを追加する際 `FieldAttribute.REQUIRED` は不要という点です。 Kotlinでモデル定義した際、型が non-nullable ならば自動的に `@Required` 扱いにするというのは github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4701 で検討中です。

モデルクラスの修正をした後に反映されてないように感じたらプロジェクトの clean を試してみてください。
`build.gradle` に `kotlin.incremental=false` を指定してインクリメンタルビルドを無効化するのも効果があるかもしれません。